# Problem running mongod with run-rs. Windows10

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, windows-10

```
C:\Users\Ashwin Bordoloi> run-rs --mongod --keep  --dbpath D:\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data
    Skipping purge
    Running 'mongod' [ 27017, 27018, 27019 ]
    Restarting replica set...
    Error: failed to start mongod with options [
      '--port=27019',
      '--dbpath=D:\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.2\\data\\27019',
      '--bind_ip=ashwin1014',
      '--replSet=rs'
    ]
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.926+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.929+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21056 port=27019 dbpath=D:\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data\27019 64-bit host=ashwin1014
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.5
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 2261279b51ea13df08ae708ff278f0679c59dc32
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.930+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "ashwin1014", port: 27019 }, replication: { replSet: "rs" }, storage: { dbPath: "D:\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data\27019" } }
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.935+0530 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
    2020-04-16T01:16:28.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48

        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ashwin Bordoloi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run-rs\node_modules\mongodb-topology-manager\lib\server.js:404:15)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

since MongoDb local environment does not allow transactions, i used run-rs to run a replicaSet. However if i use run-rs i get an error "Failed to start mongod wih options"

Comment: Please don't paste images (which is even hardly readable). Use formatted text instead.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so this is more suited to e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: is this issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is shutting down with error code 48, it seems like the resources are already consumed.

run

```
netstat -a -n | find "27019"
```

and check if port 27019 is already used

> TCP 0.0.0.0:27019 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING

Kill the process on that port and restart the mongo.